# How to pull out only one beta coefficient for each group separately from the regression equation and calculate mean by variables in R

Tags: r

here little example of my data.

```
sales.data=structure(list(MDM_Key = c(370L, 370L, 370L, 370L, 370L, 370L, 
370L, 371L, 371L, 371L, 371L, 371L, 371L, 371L), sale_count = c(30L, 
32L, 32L, 24L, 20L, 15L, 23L, 30L, 32L, 32L, 24L, 20L, 15L, 23L
), iek_disc_price = c(38227.08, 38227.08, 33739.7, 38227.08, 
38227.08, 28844.16, 31649.255, 38227.08, 38227.08, 33739.7, 38227.08, 
38227.08, 28844.16, 31649.255)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

i perform regression analysis

```
str(sales.data)
m1<-lm(formula=sale_count~iek_disc_price,data=sales.data)
summary(m1)
```

But the main difficulty is that for each group (MDM_Key) I don't need all the regression results from the `summary`, but only one `beta` coefficient.

here

```
B=0.0008559.
```

but then i need  calculate mean value for sale_count and the mean for iek_disc_price (also for each mdm key group)

so the desired result would be like this

```
MDM_Key    beta    mean(sale_count) mean(iek_disc_price)
370    0.0008559         25.14                 35305
371    0.0008559         25.14                 35305
```

How to take only  beta (nor intercept)regression coefficient for each group  `mdm_key`
and also for each group, calculate the mean values for sale_count and iek_disc_price to get the summary table indicated above.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to apply one regression per `MDM_Key`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

sales.data %>% 
  group_by(MDM_Key) %>% 
  mutate(
    mean_sale_count = mean(sale_count),
    mean_iek_disc_price = mean(iek_disc_price)
  ) %>% 
  nest(-MDM_Key,-mean_sale_count,-mean_iek_disc_price) %>% 
  mutate(
    coefs = map(.x = data,.f = ~tidy(lm(formula=.$sale_count~.$iek_disc_price,data=.)))
    ) %>%
  unnest(coefs) %>% 
  filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>% 
  select(MDM_Key,beta = estimate,mean_sale_count,mean_iek_disc_price)


# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   MDM_Key [2]
  MDM_Key     beta mean_sale_count mean_iek_disc_price
    <int>    <dbl>           <dbl>               <dbl>
1     370 0.000856            25.1              35306.
2     371 0.000856            25.1              35306.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using R base and the split + apply + combine strategy:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(sales.data, sales.data$MDM_Key), function(i) {
    c(beta=coef(lm(sale_count~iek_disc_price, data=i))[2],
      sale_count_mean=mean(i$sale_count), 
      iek_disc_price_mean=mean(i$iek_disc_price))
} ))

    beta.iek_disc_price sale_count_mean iek_disc_price_mean
370        0.0008558854        25.14286            35305.92
371        0.0008558854        25.14286            35305.92
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the means using `aggregate` and the beta values using `lmList` and then put them together and rearrange the columns in the order shown in the question.  Omit `[, c(2:1, 3:4)]` if the column order doesn't matter.  Note that nlme comes with R and does not have to be installed.

```
library(nlme) # lmList

means <- aggregate(. ~ MDM_Key, sales.data, mean)
fm <- lmList(sale_count ~ iek_disc_price | MDM_Key, sales.data)
cbind(beta = coef(fm)[, 2], means)[, c(2:1, 3:4)]

##   MDM_Key         beta sale_count iek_disc_price
## 1     370 0.0008558854   25.14286       35305.92
## 2     371 0.0008558854   25.14286       35305.92
```